# separated references for article

Tags: biblatex

I have to write about 5-6 pages long article, so that I will describe 3 different projects. I would like to have separate references at the end of each of the 3 projects. I found some examples how one would go for that in the case the documentclass is book, but it did not work out in the case of article.

I need some help.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is this question leaved?

Answer (score 2):

`refsection`s (or `refsegment`s if labels should be global) might help. Each `refsection` can be addressed by a number starting with `1`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
\section{section 1}
\cite{aaa}
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}
\section{section 2}
\cite{bbb}
\end{refsection}

\printbibliography[section=1]

\printbibliography[section=2]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it did not help.

Comment: @user193294 If this does not help, you may want to add a few more details to your question explaining *why* this did not help. Did it fail to produce any output? Did it produce the 'wrong' output? What would be the 'correct' output instead? What have you tried so far? Where do you want the bibliographies to appear, etc. etc.?

Comment: The global refsection is called `0` and all entries not in an explicit refsection will be in the global refsection. A `\printbibliography` always applied to the currently active refsection unless that is explicitly overruled (with `refsection=n` as in the example above).